# Replace loop with lapply, sapply

Tags: r, loops, lapply, sapply

I'm very new to R, and I heard it's best to replace loops with apply functions, however I couldn't wrap my head around on how to transform my loop with this example. Any help would be appreciated.

```
file_path is a list of file names
file_path[1] = "/home/user/a.rds"
file_path[2] = "/home/user/b.rds"
...

vector_sum <- rep(0,50000)
for(i in 1:5){
  temp_data <- readRDS(file_path[i])
  temp_data <- as.matrix(temp_data[,c("loss_amount")])
  vector_sum <- vector_sum + temp_data
}
```

My goal is to loop through all the files, in each file only keep loss_amount column and add it to vector_sum, so in the end vector_sum is the sum of all loss_amount columns from all files

Comment: ```it's best to replace loops with apply functions``` - that's not necessarily the case - there's no necessary performance advantage and loops are often easier to debug and are more readable. It's mostly a coding style preference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem using `lapply`:

```
sum(unlist(lapply(file_path, \(fle) readRDS(fle)[, "loss_amount"]))) 
# or
do.call(sum, lapply(file_path, \(fle) readRDS(fle)[, "loss_amount"]))
```

Comment: can you please specify what's \(fle) do here please?

Comment: `lapply` works like a loop, and `fle` is like `i` in your `for` loop. you can use any name syntactically correct. for example: `lapply(file_path, \(fle) readRDS(fle)` means _for each file/path fle in file_path, read the file fle using the function readRDS_. So, you can change `fle` to `x` or `i`, or other names you prefer

Comment: @PPAPR2022 In case you get a weird error with  _B.ChristianKamgang_'s or my code, update your R or use `function(x)` instead of  `\(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `rowSums`.

```
rowSums(sapply(file_path, \(x) readRDS(x)[, 'loss_amount'], USE.NAMES=F))
# [1]  1.2060989  1.4248851 -0.4759345
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
l <- replicate(3, matrix(rnorm(6), 3, 2, dimnames=list(NULL, c('x', 'loss_amount'))), simplify=F)
dir.create('foo')  ## creates/overwrites `foo` in wd!
Map(\(x, y) saveRDS(x, paste0('foo/', y, '.rds')), l, letters[seq_along(l)])
file_path <- list.files('foo', full.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't specify, but these solutions don't work, because I have over 200K files to loop through, so I always get a out of bounds error.

Comment: Error `Error in m[, "loss_amount"] : subscript out of bounds` means that at least one of your matrices i.e. files has no loss_amount column though, try `m <- matrix(1:12, 3, 4, dimnames=list(NULL, letters[1:4])); m[, 'f']`.